# reading a json object from a website in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to separate sub person, name, age, home addr, office addr from below given json object retrieved from a website

> { "person" :
>
> > [{"subperson":{"home":{"id":"kljljk"},"name":"person3","age":"18","addr":{"home addr":"ksdjr","office addr":"kjshdg"}}}]}

tried nsjsonserialization,sbjson and touchJSON api's. returns a dictionary in which person is the key and everything else is the value(format of json string specified below the code)
my code:

```
NSURLRequest *urlreq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlreq returningResponse:nil error:nil];
[webviv loadRequest:urlreq];
SBJsonParser *jsonparser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *json = [jsonparser objectWithData:response];
NSLog(@"%@\n", json);
for(id key in json)
{
     NSLog(@"%@=%@",key,[json objectWithKey: key]);
}

//output is
person = (everythingelse starting with [, can't separate name and other required things)

//using NSJSONSerialization
if ([NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"json");
}

NSData *pTL = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",pTL);

//Output is the same
//for(int i=0;i<[pTL count];i++)
//{
//NSLog(@"%d",i);
//}
//even with for loop the output is the same
```

Comment: Are you sure? What does json[@"person"][0][@"subperson"] return for example? NSJSONSerialization does recurse into the JSON.

Comment: did not understand what u r saying here but it shows error when i run with nslog(json[@"person"][0][@"subperson"]) and simply crashes when i run nslog(json[0][@"subperson"]) and also shows error for json[@person][0]

Comment: parsed it successfully....Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Tell your backend guys(the person who wrote this web service) to change "[" as "(" and "]" as")". ( is array { is dictionary. [ is nothing for us we can differentiate it

Comment: not possible. If it is [] then is it not json?? it is still json so i don't think there is any problem

Comment: [] with this we can't parse json or xml or soap service

Comment: i tried using json parser given by tom susel(above). it was successful

Comment: browser...it was successful for my previous employee in xcode. so i think it's possible

Comment: i parsed it successfully...so it's a json string

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your JSON structure.

For instance, the following is not a legal JSON string:

```
"subperson":"home":{"id":"kljljk"}
```

Try replacing it with the following:

`{"person":[{"subperson":{"id":"kljljk","name":"person3","age":"18","addr":{"homeaddr":"ksdjr","office addr":"kjshdg"}}}]}`

You can use any kind of [online JSON parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) tool to verify the JSON structure before continuing to debug your code.

Also you should read a little about JSON syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp).